# Perform a double integral over array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, integral

I'm performing a one dimensional integral over an array as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41226624/1391441) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347539/1391441). As stated in those answers, I can not use [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) to vectorize the integrals over the array because it employs an *adaptive* algorithm, which is why I use `numpy.trapz` below (I could also have used `scipy.integrate.simps` or `scipy.integrate.romb`)

```
import numpy as np

# Define some random data
Ndata = 500
data1 = np.random.uniform(.1, .8, Ndata)
data2 = np.random.uniform(.01, .2, Ndata)

# 1D function to integrate
def distFunc(x, c1=1., c2=.1):
    B1 = ((data1 - (1. / x)) / data2)**2
    B2 = ((x - c1) / c2)**2
    f = np.exp(-.5 * B1) * np.exp(-.5 * B2) / c2
    return f

# Values in x to evaluate the integral.
x = np.linspace(.1, 10, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

# Integral in x for each of the Ndata values defined above.
int_exp = np.trapz(distFunc(x), x, axis=0)
```

This works fine for a single dimension, but now I'd like to perform a double integral, replacing the `c2` constant by a variable:

```
# 2D function to integrate
def distFunc(x, y, c1=1.):
    B1 = ((data1 - (1. / x)) / data2)**2
    B2 = ((x - c1) / y)**2
    f = np.exp(-.5 * B1) * np.exp(-.5 * B2) / y
    return f
```

For what I could gather, the only available function is [`scipy.integrate.dblquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html) bu that means I could no longer apply the integral to an entire array in a single pass, and I would have to use a `for` loop which is considerably slower.

Is there any solution to this? I'm open to almost anything as long as it is reasonable performance-wise (I'm plugging this double-integral into an MCMC and it needs to be be evaluated millions of times)

---

**ADD**

This is  my attempt with a 1-dimensional integral using `scipy.integrate.quad` inside a `for` loop (ie: one data value in the array at a time). The process is more than 50x slower than using `np.trapz` over the entire array.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Define some random data
Ndata = 500
data1 = np.random.uniform(.1, .8, Ndata)
data2 = np.random.uniform(.01, .2, Ndata)

# Function to integrate
def distFunc2(x, data1_i, data2_i, c1=1., c2=.1):
    B1 = ((data1_i - (1. / x)) / data2_i)**2
    B2 = ((x - c1) / c2)**2
    f = np.exp(-.5 * B1) * np.exp(-.5 * B2) / c2
    return f

s = t.time()
int_exp = np.zeros(Ndata)
for i in range(Ndata):
    int_exp[i] = quad(distFunc2, .1, 10., args=(data1[i], data2[i]))[0]
print(t.time() - s)
```

---

**ADD 2**

Testing the answer given below, it *sort of works*, with the caveat that at times it can fail super hard compared to `dblquad` (which is far slower but much more precise). I'm guessing this is related to the algorithm used by `np.trapz`.

```
# Define some random data
Ndata = 10
data1 = np.random.uniform(.1, 10., Ndata)
data2 = np.random.uniform(.1, .2, Ndata)

c1 = .1
print(integ_dblquad(c1, data1, data2))
print(integ_trapz(c1, data1, data2))

def integ_dblquad(c1, data1, data2):
    def distFunc(y, x, d1_i, d2_i, c1):
        B1 = ((d1_i - (1. / x)) / d2_i)**2
        B2 = ((x - c1) / y)**2
        return (np.exp(-.5 * B1) / d2_i) * np.exp(-.5 * B2) / y

    int_exp = np.zeros(data1.size)
    for i in range(data1.size):
        int_exp[i] = dblquad(
            distFunc, .1, 10., lambda x: 0, lambda x: 5.,
            args=(data1[i], data2[i], c1))[0]

    return np.sum(np.log(int_exp))

def integ_trapz(c1, data1, data2):
    def distFunc2d(x, y):
        B1 = ((data1 - (1. / x)) / data2)**2
        B2 = ((x - c1) / y)**2
        return (np.exp(-.5 * B1) / data2) * np.exp(-.5 * B2) / y

    # Values in x to evaluate the integral.
    x = np.linspace(.1, 10, 1000)
    y = np.linspace(.1, 5., 1000)
    # Integral in x for each of the Ndata values defined above.
    int_exp2d = np.trapz(np.trapz(distFunc2d(x[:, np.newaxis], y[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]), y, axis=0), x, axis=0)

    return np.sum(np.log(int_exp2d))
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that a for-loop will be too slow? The computational time should be dominated by the internal integration routines.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog please see my edited answer. Even with a 1D integral using `quad` inside a for loop is more than 50x slower than using `np.trapz` on the entire array.

Comment: I meant using `np.trapz` in the loop

Comment: But `np.trapz` can not perform a double integral (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Oh wait, you mean using a `for` loop with `np.trapz` to perform the double integral. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, you can just call `trapz` twice:

```
import numpy as np

# Define some random data
Ndata = 500
data1 = np.random.uniform(.1, .8, Ndata)
data2 = np.random.uniform(.01, .2, Ndata)

# 1D function to integrate
def distFunc(x, c1=1., c2=.1):
    B1 = ((data1 - (1. / x)) / data2)**2
    B2 = ((x - c1) / c2)**2
    f = np.exp(-.5 * B1) * np.exp(-.5 * B2) / c2
    return f

def distFunc2d(x, y, c1=1.):
    B1 = ((data1 - (1. / x)) / data2)**2
    B2 = ((x - c1) / y)**2
    f = np.exp(-.5 * B1) * np.exp(-.5 * B2) / y
    return f

# Values in x to evaluate the integral.
x = np.linspace(.1, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(.1, 10, 100)

# Integral in x for each of the Ndata values defined above.
int_exp = np.trapz(distFunc(x[:,np.newaxis]), x, axis=0)
int_exp2d = np.trapz(np.trapz(distFunc2d(x[:,np.newaxis],y[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]), y, axis=0), x, axis=0)
```

Comment: I've edited my question commenting this answer. It *sort of* works, except it will fail miserably at times. I'm guessing this is related to `np.trapz` and not to your implementation, so if no better answer comes along, I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Yeah, trapz behind the scenes is just doing the trapezoidal integration, so you have to evaluate the function at a fine enough scale that the linear approximation it is making is a good one. It depends on the problem whether the speed up you get by evaluating everything behind the scenes in C makes up for the overhead of the extra function calls required to evaluate it at a fine grained scale. If you really need to speed it up you can of course rewrite it in C. The GSL library has functions for performing CQUAD doubly adaptive integration.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/CQUAD-doubly_002dadaptive-integration.html.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found that I can solve the integral in `y` as a gamma function, so I'm back to a single integral which runs reasonably well with `trapz`.